# Node with express - crawl and generate sitemap automatically

Tags: node.js, express, sitemap

My website changes very frequently, and I need a way to dynamically generate a new site map every day.

I tried to use [sitemap.js](https://github.com/ekalinin/sitemap.js) but it requires me to give it specific urls for my site.

I am wondering if there's a way to have it crawl the site and generate a site map based on the urls it finds dynamically.

If not, is there any other server-side script that I can use to dynamically generate site maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website does contain any backend? Or storage for data? Or is it only clean HTML and nothing more? If its any of the 1 or 2nd option, then you can just exctract it from this. Or you can 
1. get your homepage, extract all urls, 2. omit those from other domains. 3. Repeat for links that you've stored. 4. Do not store duplicates.

Comment: This is actually a simple way to go about it! Never though of that!